# parse two signs (==4==2*2) in ggplot2's annotate

Tags: r, parsing, plot, ggplot2, annotations

Is there a simply way to parse two equal signs in the same text in ggplot2's annotate or do I have to annotate twice? (i.e. replace `:` by `=` in the plot below?)

I can plot with annotate like this

```
require(ggplot2)
f <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1/1.1), y = c(1/.9, 0))
c <- ggplot(f, aes(x, y))
c + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=F)  
+ annotate("text", x=.6,y=.75, label=(paste0("slope:","frac(1, f[1])==", 
coef(lm(f$y ~ f$x))[2])), parse=TRUE)
```

Which gives me this,
[image: ====]

but I cannot have two equal signs like this,

```
f <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1/1.1), y = c(1/.9, 0))
c <- ggplot(f, aes(x, y))
c + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=F)  + annotate("text", x=.6,y=.75,
label=(paste0("slope==","frac(1, f[1])==", coef(lm(f$y ~ f$x))[2])), parse=TRUE)
```

I get this error.

```
Error in parse(text = lab) : <text>:1:23: unexpected '=='
1: slope==frac(1, f[1])==
                          ^
```

In my real case I have several fractions, I realize that my working example is very simply and one might ask why replace `:` by `=`, but it's a working example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1/1.1), y = c(1/.9, 0))
c <- ggplot(f, aes(x, y))
c <- c + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=F) + annotate("text", x=.6,y=.75, label=(paste0("slope==~frac(1,f[1])==", coef(lm(f$y ~ f$x))[2])), parse=TRUE)

plot(c)
```

Edited. Plot is:

[image]

Comment: nicely done, what is the the `~` doing?  `?plotmath` is a POS

Comment: @Rorschach. I think it's adding a space.