# using bold in mtext on string coming from vector element

Tags: r, plot

I've learned to apply bold to a portion of the text used in a plot title using mtext() expression() and paste(). This works great if you specify the strings outright.  However, in the project I'm working on now, the portion of text to be bolded needs to be obtained through a call to an element of a vector. However, the characters needed in the call syntax are interpreted by expression() and the call fails.

```
junk <- c("I'm Special", "You're Special")
plot(0, type="n")
mtext(expression(paste("Do you think ", bold(junk[1]),"today?")),3,2)
mtext(expression(paste("I think ", bold(junk[2]), "today.")),3,1)
```

Any thoughts on how to approach this?  I am trying to avoid specifying the bold text directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bquote` has a decent interface for this.  You just surround the variable you want to substitute with `.()`.  You could also use `substitute` with `expression`.

```
junk <- c("I'm Special", "You're Special")
plot(0, type="n")
mtext(bquote(paste("Do you think ", bold(.(junk[1])),"today?")),3,2)
mtext(bquote(paste("I think ", bold(.(junk[2])), "today.")),3,1)
```

Comment: I also like to use `~` rather than `paste()` myself: `mtext(bquote("Do you think "~ bold(.(junk[1]))~ "today?"),3,2)`

Comment: @MrFlick interesting... what is happening there?

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was on the `?plotmath` page but can't find it now. Basically it's like an operator that puts two expressions next to each other with a space `plot(1,1,main=expression(a~b))`

Comment: @MrFlick thankyou!  I was on here earlier today and saw a similar answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132881/parse-two-signs-4-22-in-ggplot2s-annotate/33133237#comment54079220_33133237) but it wasnt explained.

Comment: Wow, thank you both very much.  I recall using bquote() a looong time ago but never adopted it (forgot about it actually).  I'll need to revisit it.  The tilde operator for "pasting" is totally new to me.  I use paste() and paste0() a lot.  I'll check this out too.

Comment: @WillPhillips the tilde that MrFlick is using there is special because it is inside the `bquote` expression.  It won't be if it is just inside a `paste`, although I'm still trying to grok it.