# r plot text adding variable for text to be bolded

Tags: r, plot

In the example below, the variable holds the letter a. But the legend in legend just returns temp rather than a bolded a. How to make this work like it 'should'?

```
a <- 2
b <- 5
temp <- letters[1]
temp
plot(a,b)

legend("topleft", legend = c(as.expression(bquote(bold(get(temp)))),
                             as.expression(bquote(temp))))
```

Comment: like this? `legend("topleft", legend = parse(text = c(sprintf('bold(%s)', temp), temp)))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using bold in mtext on string coming from vector element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137727/using-bold-in-mtext-on-string-coming-from-vector-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two responses helped me to get to an answer for me. I asked the question  about legend. I'm using the plot functions in the terra package and the answers didn't work in the legend option in terra::plot. But this code does if you replace x and y with the relevant coordinates in your plot.

```
text(x, y, cex = 1.5, (bquote(paste((bold(.(a)))))))
```

It's extremely ungainly to look at but trying to add say a space in that string of parentheses after the 'a' for clarity didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Building off the answer from here: [using bold in mtext on string coming from vector element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137727/using-bold-in-mtext-on-string-coming-from-vector-element)

In order to tell `bquote` to evaluate a variable, instead of simply printing it as text, you need to wrap the term in `.()`, which causes it to instead evaluate it in the specified environment (given by the `where` argument).

```
temp <- 'a'
e <- new.env()
assign('temp','b',envir = e)
plot(2,5)
legend("topleft",
       legend = c(as.expression(
           bquote(bold(temp))),                 # No .(), `temp` is text
           bquote(bold(.(temp))),               # eval `temp` in parent.env
           bquote(bold(.(temp)), where = e)))   # eval `temp` in envir "e"
```

[image]

The help for `?bquote` mentions this:

> bquote quotes its argument except that terms wrapped in `.()` are evaluated in the specified `where` environment